# Formato fecha mes en ingles

Tags: python, date, datetime

espero estén bien. Estoy intentando seleccionar unas fechas con el siguiente formato:

```
July 1, 2021
```

Sin embargo, no he podido seleccionarlas debido al formato del día. Existe alguna forma de quitarle el cero al uno? este es el código que utilizo.

```
# Dates
yesterday = date.today() + timedelta(days=-1)
now = datetime.now() # current date and time
ahora = now.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H_%M_%S")
print("Inicio de prueba: "+str(now))

tomorrow = now + timedelta(days=1)
mañana = datetime.strftime(tomorrow,'%B %d, %Y').lstrip('0')
```

La parte que necesito editar es la anterior, la que aparece como "mañana"; ya que el formato que me da es el siguiente

```
July 01, 2021
```

Pero yo necesito que el resultado se este: `July 1, 2021.`

Como podría quitarle el cero al 1?

Comment: Sería recomendable que coloques el código hasta ahora trabajado-

Comment: Hola, crees que sea necesario? el formato que tengo me da: Jul 1, 2021 pero yo necesito July 1, 2021. No encuentro la forma de que el mes salga completo, no solo los tres primeros caracteres.

Comment: Es necesario para ver la variable que usas para el datatime, y también por políticas de la comunidad. Revisa [ask] Verás que en lo que coloques el código mínimo necesario será más fácil darte una respuesta precisa

Comment: Si sabes que por defecto te lo da en inglés?

Comment: Hola, ya corregí la pregunta, lo siento, soy nuevo en esto. @JeanGotopo; Si @Christian, lo sé, la pregunta exacta la acabo de editar. Gracias

Comment: Fijate que hasta la pregunta cambia, porque anteriormente no habías aclarado lo de quitar el 0 al 01. Por eso es importante el código para no generar confusiones. Trataré de modificar mi respuesta

Comment: tienes toda la razón, @JeanGotopo, gracias por las correcciones.

Comment: He editado la pregunta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cambia %b por %B, que usa el nombre completo en vez del nombre corto.

```
from datetime import datetime
date_time_str = "July 1, 2021"

date_time_obj = datetime.strptime(date_time_str, "%B %d, %Y")
print(date_time_obj)

date_time_obj_str = datetime.strftime(date_time_obj, "Hoy es %d de %B del año %Y")
print(date_time_obj_str)
```

Y para quitar el 0 en el dia, se usa %-d en vez de %d. Ejemplo:

```
from datetime import datetime
date_time_str = "July 1, 2021"

date_time_obj = datetime.strptime(date_time_str, "%B %d, %Y")
print(date_time_obj)

date_time_obj_str = datetime.strftime(date_time_obj, "Hoy es %-d de %B del año %Y")
print(date_time_obj_str)
```

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por tus comentarios, he intentado de la forma en la que me dices y me da el siguiente error: 

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-106-45ac93f9ab72> in <module>()
     16 
     17 tomorrow = now + timedelta(days=1)
---> 18 mañana = datetime.strftime(tomorrow,'%B %-d, %Y').lstrip('0')

ValueError: Invalid format string

Comment: A ver si consigo ponerte bien el código  `from datetime import date   
from datetime import timedelta   
  
yesterday = date.today() + timedelta(days=-1)  
now = datetime.now() # current date and time  
ahora = now.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H_%M_%S")  
print("Inicio de prueba: "+str(now))  
  
tomorrow = now + timedelta(days=1)  
mañana = datetime.strftime(tomorrow,'%B %-d, %Y').lstrip('0')  
  
print(mañana)`

Comment: @ARL esita tu respuesta y se más detallado en el comentario que das, pues solo muestra el código pero no dices que cambio y por que

Comment: @Christian el código representa la solicitud que ha pedido el autor. En la respuesta está comentado cada uno de las aportaciones y qué representa cada opción de formato.

Comment: encontré esto, tu formato @ARL esta correcto pero sería unicamente para linux, para windows sería de esta forma "%B %#d, %Y" Muchas gracias por los comentarios y aportes, ya pude solucionar.

Comment: ¡Muy bien @CarlosPeñaloza!

Comment: @CarlosPeñaloza si la repuesta soluciino tu problema, marcala como aceptada

Comment: @Christian, disculpame, donde puedo realizar esto? con mucho gusto lo hago, solo que como lo comenté, soy nuevo en esto, no sé muy bien muchas cosas. te lo agradecería.

Answer (score 2):

Con el character code %B (en mayúscula) se formatea el nombre completo del mes. Tu código quedaría así:

```
import datetime

yesterday = datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=-1)
now = datetime.datetime.now() # current date and time

ahora = now.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H_%M_%S")
print("Inicio de prueba: "+str(now))

tomorrow = now + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
manana = datetime.datetime.strftime(tomorrow,'%B %d, %Y')
corte = manana.split() #Con este divido manana en un arreglo de varios string para luego sacar el mes y el año
mes=corte[0]
year = corte[2]
dia=tomorrow.day #el día no lo saco del arreglo porque te daría '01' y no quieres eso, con este método sale sin cero
print(mes, dia, ',', year)
```

La salida será July 1, 2021

Comment: Correcto, esa parte la encontré y la hice tal cual, el problema es el cero en el día. Ya corregí la pregunta e inserte el código. Quedo atento

Comment: Si, había colocado la respuesta que viste antes que el OP editara la pregunta, edición que cambió considerablemente a la primera. Ya edité mi respuesta.

Comment: Editada la respuesta de acuerdo al código presentado por @CarlosPeñaloza

Comment: muchas gracias, es usted muy amable, le agradezco.